# trying to enable a user to see the letsencrypt keys

Tags: bash, acl

I do not know if this is the right place to ask, but I'l give it a try

I was trying to let user **mysql** read the **letsencrypt** keys.
Normally any user can see the **live** and the **archive** folders so the mysql user can also

```
debian:~# sudo -u mysql ls /etc/letsencrypt/archive/
example1.com example2.com example3.com
```

if I try to see the files in there

```
debian:~# sudo -u mysql ls /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example1.com
ls: Zugriff auf /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example1.com/ nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung
```

(what means in german : you have no right to see the files.)
then I garbed **setfacl** and tried to gain mysql access to the files, so I went:

```
setfacl -R -m "u:mysql:r" /etc/letsencrypt/archive/
```

then I checked the acl

```sh
debian:~# getfacl /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example1.com
getfacl: Entferne führende '/' von absoluten Pfadnamen
# file: etc/letsencrypt/archive/example1.com
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
user:mysql:r--
group::r-x
mask::r-x
other::r-x
```

then I became confident and praised myself, as I always do when I do smart things
For some reason I checked again :

```
debian:~# sudo -u mysql ls /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example1.com
ls: Zugriff auf /etc/letsencrypt/archive/example1.com/ nicht möglich: Keine Berechtigung
```

the user mysql still sees nothing. (setfacl --version 2.2.52)
Is there something I missed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the **executable bit** (x) on the folder as well for a user to be able to actually navigate into the directory. Try the following:

```sh
setfacl -m "u:mysql:rx" /etc/letsencrypt/archive/
setfacl -R -m "u:mysql:r" /etc/letsencrypt/archive/*
```

Comment: with one comment that -R recursive seems to not work like it should. Now all files are executables